# Aligning Boxes next to eachother

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 simple boxes that I would like to align horizontally next to each other. But currently they are just stacking on-top of each other vertically. I am using Twitter Boostrap as well for the 'row' class.

**HTML:**

```css
.img-box-kai {
        width: 300px;
        height: 450px;
        border: 3px solid red;
    }
    
    .img-box-lucas {
        width: 300px;
        height: 450px;
        border: 3px solid red;
    }
    
    .img-box-bryant {
        width: 300px;
        height: 450px;
        border: 3px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="img-box-kai">Rectangle Test</div>
        <div class="img-box-lucas">Rectangle Test</div>
        <div class="img-box-bryant">Rectangle Test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is what they look like currently: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHIgu.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend on using Bootstrap, you'll want to remove the set widths and use the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) to stack them horizontally using Bootstrap:

```css
.img-box-kai {
    height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-box-lucas {
    height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-box-bryant {
    height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 img-box-kai">Rectangle Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 img-box-lucas">Rectangle Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 img-box-bryant">Rectangle Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kstullich I would strongly suggest you read up on the Bootstrap documentation. There is a lot you can do with that framework. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: @kstullich if you've found the answer helpful to you, please mark it as accepted so it can help others.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` on `.row`, like:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.img-box-kai {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-box-lucas {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-box-bryant {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}


.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Aligning Horizontally */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img-box-kai">Rectangle Test</div>
    <div class="img-box-lucas">Rectangle Test</div>
    <div class="img-box-bryant">Rectangle Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add float:left to each of them.
like

```
  .img-box-kai {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    float:left;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-box-lucas {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    float:left;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-box-bryant {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    float:left;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I tried that they are still stacking on-top of each other

Comment: ok. it means your container's width is less than total width of these boxes.

Comment: so you need to use bootstrap's grid.try adding class .col-md-4 to each of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code and will work.

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
  }
```

```css
.img-box-kai {
            width: 300px;
            height: 450px;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }
        
        .img-box-lucas {
            width: 300px;
            height: 450px;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }
        
        .img-box-bryant {
            width: 300px;
            height: 450px;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }

       .row{
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row
       }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="img-box-kai">Rectangle Test</div>
            <div class="img-box-lucas">Rectangle Test</div>
            <div class="img-box-bryant">Rectangle Test</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## You need to use Bootstrap class to each of them. like

### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img-box-kai col-md-4 pull-left">Rectangle Test</div>
    <div class="img-box-lucas col-md-4 pull-left">Rectangle Test</div>
    <div class="img-box-bryant col-md-4 pull-left">Rectangle Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.img-box-kai {
    min-height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-box-lucas {
    min-height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-box-bryant {
    min-height: 450px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```